# Mathematica solving complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers, equation-solving, mathematica-8

If I have a complex equation in the form of

```
   Solve[z^2 + 9 - 1.5 E^[-tz]==0, z]
   where z = x + I y
   where x , y  and t are all assumed to be real.
```

How do I tell Mathematica 9 to separate the real and imaginary parts to make
two equations in the form of

```
   Re[z]==0, Im[z]==0.
```

I try this

```
    myConjugate[eqn_Equal] := myConjugate /@ eqn
    myConjugate[expr_] := expr /. {I -> -I, a_Complex :> Conjugate[a]}
    myRe[eqn_Equal] := myRe /@ eqn
    myRe[expr_] := (expr + myConjugate[expr])/2
    myIm[eqn_Equal] := myIm /@ eqn
    myIm[expr_] := (expr - myConjugate[expr])/(2 I)
```

and

```
{myRe[#], myIm[#]} &[(x + I y)^2 + 9 - 1.5 E[- t (x+ I y)] == 0]
```

Comment: @ High Performance Mark thanks for your advice. It have done.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? What kind of result are you expecting in the end?